# Problemas al intentar scanera una tarjeta NFC con xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nfc

Buenas estoy intentando escanear una tarjeta ***NFC*** con una aplicación desarrollada en **swift y xcode** en un Telefono **Iphone X**. Creo el ID para poder usar el nfc, hago los cambios en el archivo **info.plist** y creo el código necesario (por lo menos eso creo je).
La cuestión que ejecuto la aplicación y me sale el cartel listo para escanear pero no escanea la tarjeta y después se cierra por exceso de tiempo en ejecución.

```
import UIKit
import CoreNFC

class NFCViewController: UIViewController, 
UINavigationBarDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate, 
NFCNDEFReaderSessionDelegate{

@IBOutlet var webview: UIWebView!
@IBOutlet weak var Menu: UIBarButtonItem!
var session: NFCNDEFReaderSession?


let urlNombre = "http://www.google.com"
let DatoNFC = "/"


func readerSession(_ session: NFCNDEFReaderSession, didInvalidateWithError error: Error) {
    print(error.localizedDescription)

    _ = NFCNDEFReaderSession(delegate: self, queue: DispatchQueue(label: "queueName", attributes: .concurrent), invalidateAfterFirstRead: false)
    print("ingresa mal")


}

func readerSession(_ session: NFCNDEFReaderSession, didDetectNDEFs messages: [NFCNDEFMessage]) {
     print("ingresa bien")
    for message in messages {
        for record in message.records {
            if let DatoNFC = String(data: record.payload, encoding: .ascii) {
                print(DatoNFC)

                if let url = URL(string: urlNombre+DatoNFC){
                    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
                    self.webview.loadRequest(request)

                }

            }
        }
    }
}





override func viewDidLoad() {

super.viewDidLoad()
     print("ingresa")


    session = NFCNDEFReaderSession(delegate: self, queue: DispatchQueue(label: "queueName", attributes: .concurrent), invalidateAfterFirstRead: false)
    session?.begin()


    //TRAIGO LA PAGINA WEB Y LA INSERTO EN EL WEBVIEW
  /*  if let url = URL(string: urlNombre+DatoNFC){
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        self.webview.loadRequest(request)

    }*/

    //PEMITO QUE EL BOTON SANDWICHT ESTÉ DISPONIBLE Y ACTIVO EN LA PARTE SUPERIOR
    if revealViewController() != nil {

        Menu.target = revealViewController()
        Menu.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))

    }


 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

El código funciona perfecto. Lo que no sabia es que Apple solo permite hacer lectura de tarjetas para pagos de sus productos nada mas o bancos asociados. Se los dejo por las dudas les sirva el codigo o éste comentario/respuesta. Saludos